# What are the differences between levels of Doom Bots?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know that the higher the level you pick, the more difficult the doom bots become, but what exactly are the differences between levels? Level 100 had rockets of some kind shooting from the nexus, and level 10 did not, and the bots seemed to have more hp and damage. So, what exact buffs do the doom bots get as their level increases?

Comment: Those "rockets" were probably just the mega blinding darts. It's one of the possible curses and nothing to do with doom level.

Answer (score 2):

I simply would not play each level and record their buff, but i can tell you i have played lv 40, lv 50, lv60, lv70 and lv100.

For the experiences i had learnt, their stats increases.

> **Defensive** part like health point, armor and magic resist is increasing dramatically. The higher the difficulty level, the higher
>   the stats.
>
> **Offensive** part is that their skill level is increasing , and their skill have more advance effect. The higher the difficulty level, the
>   crazier the skills they have.
>
> **Buff** They have special one like granting the protection from champions like Pantheon's Aegis Protection and Malzahar's Void Shift
>   and etc.
>
> **Terrain Buff** like shooting blinding arrows, burning bushes and electrical tower.
>
> **Jungle Monster** there will be more monster running towards your lane and attack your turret.

Few things to take note of Doom bots:

1. They never recall back to fountain even they are low in health.
2. They will start moving out from your lane to others when your turret is destroyed (In case they already destroyed your first turret).
3. They will go looking for the outer turrets which are yet to be destroyed, for example if your tier 3 turret is almost destroyed and in other lane they still have the middle one, then they will go there.
4. They are aggressive bots, deadly.
5. Once you survive 15 minutes, they will summon the Teemo. They then will start to push mid until your nexus breaks down.